# Change Jekyll URLs for blog posts

Tags: jekyll

I am currently using Jekyll to host my [blog](https://trstringer.com). The theme I'm using is [Chirpy](https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy). Currently my blog posts are being published as `trstringer.com/posts/blog-post-1`.

Is there a way to change/modify this so that it is published as `trstringer.com/blog-post-1`? I'd like to "remove" the `posts` components of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this with a permalink: `permalink: /:title/`.

Comment: Well done. Global permalinks are described in the Jekyll documentation: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#global